# Insert Database Yii with plain SQL

Tags: php, sql, yii

Need Help for insert a data with plain SQL on Yii PHP Framework.

I have this Form Code on "views/name/index.php"

```
<form name="insertname" style="display: inline" method="POST" action="name/create" id="insertname" role="form">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span5">
                            <input type="text" name="name"  class="span12" placeholder="Ex : Superman, Robocop" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="span5">
                            <select name="status" class="span12" required>
                                <option value="">Select Permission</option>
                                <option value="0">Blocked</option>
                                <option value="1">Allowed</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary glyphicons circle_ok" value="Submit"><i></i>Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And this syntax of actionCreate() on "controllers/NameController.php"

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Name;

    **$name =  $this->input->post('name');
    $status =  $this->input->post('status');**
    $insert = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO name (name,soundexcode,status) VALUES (:name,(SELECT SOUNDEX(:name)),:status)");
    $insert->bindValue(":name",$name);
    $insert->bindValue(":status",$status);
    $insert->execute();

    $data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('name, soundexcode, status')
            ->from('name')
            ->queryAll();
    $this->render('index', array(
        'data' => $data,
    ));
}
```

My Question is, how i can get the "name" and "status" data from view to controller.? And ho i could send a success/failed notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use $_POST, there is nothing wrong to use it.

```
$name =  $_POST['name'];
$status =  $_POST['status'];
```

Comment: Like `Yii::app()->request->getPost('name');`

Comment: Thanks So Much. It Works. Sorry. Im a newbie in Yii

Answer (score 0):

See Yii::app()->request->getPost('name');

Notification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get